# how to overcome command line string limitation?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, dos

Command line has a string limitation as mentioned on [msdn](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/10/56028.aspx).

I tried the workaround suggested on msdn, writing the arguments to a file. But, I am unable to pass the arguments from a file.

Edit :
I need to run the bcp utility, in order to export (huge) data to flat files.

Comment: If that's really true, then the short answer is that you're probably screwed. But if you provide more details about what you're running, maybe there are other ways to approach the problem.

Comment: what's making up most of those arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The executable you're running has to support this explicitly. For example, the C# compiler allows you to write

```
csc @foo
```

to load some options from a file called `foo`. I don't believe this can *easily* be "fixed" without support from the command you're running though... it's possible that you could write a small wrapper program which loaded the file and started the process itself. However, you'd have to be careful in terms of security handles, propagating console input and output etc. If you're in control of the application in question, you'd be much better off putting support in directly.